# Using SharePoint as a Backend

Tags: workflow

I need to build a commercial service that provides a collaboration workflow.

I'm pretty sure that I could build the entire thing in SharePoint, but since it's build for 'non-tech' people, I need to hide nearly everything 'SharePoint'.

this is probably a simplistic question but my searches have turned up either 'making a webpart' or using WCF.

I just want to build a crazy simple front end on SharePoint magic.

As I'm sure that I'm not the first person to need this, can someone tell me the Magic Words to search for?

thank you,

Gene

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hakoman/archive/2010/05/26/using-sharepoint-as-a-back-end-server-introduction.aspx

Comment: Thanks Supermode.  This is the use WCF approach that I found earlier.  Do you know if it's possible to configure a SharePoint site in such a way that I can hide all the built-in Sharepoint that I don't want and add webparts for the features I want?